# ggplot solution to PCR results

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I'm trying to plot the results of a PCR in ggplot as a biplot style figure. My ultimate goal is to depict two PCA axes with points as bubbles scaled to the size of the response variable and also with vectors overlayed to depict the correlation of the response with the PCA inputs. I tried using ggplot_pca() but this function is not recognized in ggplot2. Here is some sample data using mtcars:

```
require(pls)
require(ggplot2)

car_dat <- mtcars %>%
            select(mpg, cyl, hp, wt, qsec)

pcr_out <- pcr(mpg ~ cyl + hp + wt +qsec, validation="CV", data = car_dat)
summary(pcr_out)
```

Ultimately, I want to plot the results of the PCR on two axes, with the mpg point size scaled to the mpg value, and with a total of four vectors (one vector each for cyl, hp, wt, and qsec) that align with the correlation of the response (mpg).

**EDIT 1**

Looks like prcomp() and passing ggfortify() through ggplot does the trick.

```
require(pls)
require(ggplot2)
require(plotly)
require(ggfortify)


car_dat <- mtcars %>%
            select(mpg, cyl, hp, wt, qsec)


pcr_comp <- prcomp(~ cyl + hp + wt +qsec, data = car_dat)


p<-autoplot(pcr_comp, data=car_dat, colour="cyl", loadings=TRUE,
            loadings.label=TRUE, size="mpg")

ggplotly(p)
```